# NSArray with NSPredicate using NOT IN

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray that I want to filter out certain objects using an NSPredicate, I was hoping I could use NOT IN since I saw that I can easily do an IN.

So I have my array:

```
self.categoriesList
```

Then I get the values I want to remove:

```
NSArray *parentIDs = [self.cateoriesList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.ParentCategoryID"];
```

This gives me a list of ParentCategoryID's for categories I DO NOT want to display, so I figure I can use an NSPredicate to remove them:

```
self.cateoriesList = [self.cateoriesList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CategoryID NOT IN %@",parentIDs]];
```

This fails:

```
reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "CategoryID NOT IN %@"'
```

If I wanted to use just IN that works perfectly of course.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

What about `NOT (CategoryID IN %@)`?

Answer (score 3):

How about using `NONE`?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE CategoryID IN %@", parentIDs];
```

Comment: Note that NONE is only for to-many relationship. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127618/nspredicate-the-left-hand-side-for-an-all-or-any-operator-must-be-either-an-nsa