# NSPredicate 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or NSSet'

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Not totally sure why this isn't working now, i thought it had been working previously. Does anyone see an issue with this FetchRequest construction?

```
- (NSArray *)entriesForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Entry"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY addedOn.unique like %@", [T3Utility identifierForDate:date]];
    request.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [self.database.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return matches;
}
```

Again, i'm 99% sure that this code has been working until recently, so im thinking perhaps there's something else going on in my code somewhere . . .but when i run it through the debugger this is where is hangs. Here is my error:

The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or NSSet

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What are the attributes and relationships of your entities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `addedOn` is not a to-many relationship. Make sure you use the correct names of your attributes / relationships in the predicate. Also, note that you cannot use a to-one relationship in a "ANY" predicate.

Comment: +1 specifically, either `addedOn` needs to be to-many, with `unique` being a property (or to-one relationship), or `addedOn` needs to be to-one and `unique` needs to be a to-many relationship.