# NSPredicate - case insensitive filtering for multiple conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I'm using following NSPredicate for filtering,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName CONTAINS %@ ) OR (lastName CONTAINS %@  )OR (UserName CONTAINS %@ )  ", myText,myText,myText];
NSArray *filtered = [responseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

It works fine, but it's case-sensitive. I need the filtering should be case insensitive.

I've tried,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY firstName CONTAINS %@ ) OR (ANY lastName CONTAINS %@  )OR (ANY UserName CONTAINS %@ )  ", myText,myText,myText];
```

But it throws the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'
```

I can't understand what it was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128386/756941). Can anyone suggest what should I change here in the above filtering?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace all `CONTAINS` with `CONTAINS[c]`. The "c" in square brackets means case insensitive. You can also use a "d" to make it diacritic insensitive. This is explained in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

Comment: It's working thanks. I'll google all my coding issues instead of seeing apple documentation. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669433/756941) led me to use `ANY` keyword for case insensitive. Please add the link where it is mentioned in Predicate Programming guide..