# Compare 2 NSMutableArrays and remove duplicate records

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 `NSMutableArray`s. They are:

```
allStudentsMutableArr
selectedStudentsMutableArr
```

`allStudentsMutableArr` contains all the `Student` objects and it has around 100 objects saved in it. Whereas, `selectedStudentsMutableArr` only contains 10 `Student` records saved in it.

Now i need to compare the 2 MutableArrays and remove all objects from `allStudentsMutableArr` that's present in `selectedStudentsMutableArr` mutable array. How can i do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArray with NSPredicate using NOT IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580715/nsarray-with-nspredicate-using-not-in)

Comment: `NSMutableSet` and `–minusSet:`... IMHO is the best way to do such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
[allStudentsMutableArr removeObjectsInArray:selectedStudentsMutableArr];
```

Comment: Thanks. This sorted it. I will accept this as an answer shortly.

Comment: Welcome and feel free to ask for any other help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSPredicate as below...(Gadhiya solution also useful..)

Suppose you have student object with name as one of property then..//or any property that you want to compare and filter..

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"!(name IN %@)", selectedStudentsMutableArr];
NSArray* filteredArray = [allStudebtsMutableArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Hope it helps you..