# NSPredicate format issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

My Entity `Office` have set of `File` entities. Each `File` has `uuid` property. I need to fetch `offices` where we have any `file` where `UUID` is not in `set of Strings`

I tried to use

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (ALL files.uuid IN %@)", uuidSet)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY files.uuid NOT IN %@", uuidSet)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY NOT files.uuid IN %@", uuidSet)
```

I always get the error like

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate NOT ALL files.uuid IN {"C0DF0E67-ED8A-4D3B-87A1-E4E7B86967AA"}'
```

Is there a way to write this Predicate properly? Because right now I only see the solution to load all offices and then iterate through every item.

Comment: let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT(files.uuid IN %@)", uuidSet) take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580715/nsarray-with-nspredicate-using-not-in

Comment: @SandeepBhandari , in the provided question CategoryId is just property for one object. But in my case files are set of objects. So it gives the error "exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (files.uuid IN {"C0DF0E67-ED8A-4D3B-87A1-E4E7B86967AA"})'"