# NSPredicate: search for an array of values in relation, NOT

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nscompoundpredicate

I'm a bit lost, and I hope you can help me.

I have two arrays

```
let stars = ["Paul", "Ringo"]
let visitors = ["bob", "mary"]
```

Then I have Core Data entities **Rockstar** and **Person**. And a one-to-many relation **fans** between the two.

Now I want to find a couple of specific Rockstars, and make sure that they don't have visitors as fans.

I try to do that with a compound predicate, roughly like this:

```
let starsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", stars)
let fansPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (fans.personid CONTAINS %@)", visitors)
```

and finally

```
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [starsPredicate, fansPredicate])
```

I'm afraid this results in two questions:

1. What is the correct syntax for the fansPredicate? It works fine with one value, but it crashes on an array
2. Is this possible with a compound predicate at all? I think if the **Person** entity is empty, I get zero records from the compoundPredicate.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the same logic "IN" for fans? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580715/nsarray-with-nspredicate-using-not-in then ?

Comment: tried that, crashes

Comment: If it crashes, you might want to share the error message in console?

Comment: [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x2828a8380> , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (fans.personid IN {"173A0057-C55D-4F1E-9CD8-42627813F822"}) with userInfo of (null)

Comment: You probably need a SUBQUERY, something like `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(fans, $f, $f.personid IN %@).@count = 0", visitors)`

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. That is what I was thinking. I'm just not very good at SQL stuff. But this makes sense. I will give it a try

Comment: @MartinR: I think you nailed it. Feel free to post it as an answer. I will reward you. You basically answered both my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a “SUBQUERY”:

```
let fansPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(fans, $f, $f.personid IN %@).@count = 0",
                                visitors)
```

The predicate is true for all **Rockstar** objects which have no related **Person** object whose `personId` is in the given list.